# How declare return type as inner class of template typename?

Tags: c++, templates

How declare this:

```
template<typename T>
(T::ABC)& get();
```

it gives error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct form is without parentheses

```
typename T::ABC
```

because the form with parentheses

```
(typename T::ABC)
```

is a cast operator and not a type!

Moreover, the keyword `typename` is required because `T:ABC` is a "dependent type": if you don't use `typename`, the expression `T:ABC` is interpreted as if ABC were a member of the class T, and not a nested type).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `typename` keyword:

```
template<typename T>
typename T::ABC& get();
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be:

```
template<typename T>
typename T::ABC& get();
```

but i tried, which don't works:

```
template<typename T>
(typename T::ABC)& get();
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it too and realised that. I don't know why it doesn't work with brackets!